# Firebase Realtime database not saving POJO containing List or Map attributes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this POJO:

```
public class Person{
    private String id;
    private List phoneNumbers=new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<String,String> fcmTokens;
    //getters + Setters + default constructor are present
}
```

In the Activity: 
I try to save this object to Firebase Realtime DB using the below code, but only the String id value is saved! What am I missing here?

```
Person p= new Person();
p.setUid("123");
List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
list.add("123);
list.add("23");
p.setPhoneNumbers(list);
Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
map.put("asdf","asdfas");
map.put("23","@3r");
p.setFcmTokens(map);
mPersonNodeReference.setValue(p);
```

Comment: I think push() method will be suitable to add all values

Comment: Please add also the setters of your `Person` class. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

check if u havent add a Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)

```
public class Person{
       public Person() {

    }
}
```

remark:  inconsistent variable naming.

Answer (score 0):

To add nested fields like this in Firebase you should stay away from arrays and use a `Map` per the official documentation. So for your case, it'd be something along the lines of

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setUid("123");
//List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();   //this will not work unless you push a new key for every value added to the list
//list.add("123");
//list.add("23");
Map<String,String> mapPhoneNumbers = new HashMap<>();
mapPhoneNumbers.put("1","123");
mapPhoneNumbers.put("2","23");
p.setPhoneNumbers(mapPhoneNumbers);
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
p.setFcmTokens(map)   //not sure what barber is?
mPersonNodeReference.setValue(p);  //did you mean p?
```

Answer (score 0):

A. in activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    //your code.
}
```

B. app-level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    enter code here

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

C. project-level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
    /*classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' <-- do not use this version*/
}
```